# Perform nested grouping using lodash based on moment timestamp

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I currently have the following interface:

```
export interface IFoo {
    id: any;
    notes?: string;
    timestamp: any;
}
```

The API I am working with currently returns an array of this interface such as:

```
[{
    "id": 47,
    "notes": "asdas",
    "timestamp": "03/15/2020 08:47:42"
}, {
    "id": 48,
    "notes": "asdasd",
    "timestamp": "03/15/2020 15:16:12"
}]
```

How feasible is it to transform the above into the below structure? Knowing that I am using an Observable to load the data so I would require the use of rxjs:

```
this.foo$ = this.fooService.load
        .pipe(...
```

Essentially after using `map` or any other possible operators the response should be divided as below: (Year, Month, Day)

```
[
    {
        year: YYYY,
        count: 0, // <- total `foos` in year
        months: [
            {
                month: 'January',
                count: 0, // <- total `foos` in month
                days: [
                    {
                        day: 0,
                        count: 0, // <- total `foos` in day
                        foos: [
                            {
                                Id: 0,
                                Notes: '...',
                                Timestamp: '...'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The reason for this is that I am trying to display the data on the front end in a way where the main group is a year, the second month, day and each item under their respective day.

I have done the grouping on the back end, however, I am more convinced that this needs to be done on the front end for filtering and data manipulation purposes without going back to the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *'I have done the grouping on the back end, however, I am more convinced that this needs to be done on the front end for filtering and data manipulation purposes without going back to the server.'* -- Why so? IMO, that's what the backend is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain Javascript without *moment* and *lodash*, you could take an array for the nested groupsm with

- key,
- callback for the getting a key,
- children property, for the next nested level.

Then iterate the data and the group array and add for each level one for the count and at the end push the object to `foos`.

```js
var data = [{ id: 47, notes: "asdas", timestamp: "2020-03-15 08:47:42" }, { id: 48, notes: "asdasd", timestamp: "2020-03-15 15:16:12" }],
    groups = [
        ['year', ({ timestamp }) => timestamp.slice(0, 4), 'month'],
        ['month', ({ timestamp }) => timestamp.slice(5, 7), 'days'],
        ['days', ({ timestamp }) => timestamp.slice(8, 10), 'foos']
    ],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        groups
            .reduce((parent, [key, fn, children]) => {
                var group = parent.find(q => q[key] === fn(o));
                if (!group) parent.push(group = { [key]: fn(o), count: 0, [children]: [] });
                group.count++;
                return group[children];
            }, r)
            .push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What are the implications of doing this on the front end for say a list of 10,000+ entries?